# Merging an array of arrays with a simple array

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I'd like to merge two arrays in one but the indexes have to be respected as data are dynamics

I've tried this :

```
labels[0].forEach(element=>{
  labels[0]=(element.map((e, i) => e +','+ tableauCompare[i]));
})
```

but I get two strings

**My Input:**

```
[
    ["string1", "string2","string3"],
    ["string1b", "string2b","string3b"]
]

["string4", "string4b"]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[
    ["string1", "string2","string3","string4"],
    ["string1b", "string2b","string3b", "string4b"]
]
```

I expect a new array, like the last one, but I get an array with two strings

Comment: Also how you merge 2 arrays and respect the indexes at the same time.
If on one array you have arr1[0] = 'Test' and arr2[0] = 'Test2' how you respect the index????? You can merge and respect, the only solution for that is yo create and object and again it is now the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `map()` you can use [**`Array.prototype.push()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [**`Array.prototype.concat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like the following way:

```js
var labels = [
    ["string1", "string2","string3"],
    ["string1b", "string2b","string3b"]
]
var tableauCompare = ["string4", "string4b"];
var res = [];
labels.forEach((element, i)=>{
  res.push(element.concat(tableauCompare[i]));
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: you mutate the original data.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a **[`.map()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** call on the first `array` and concat each element with the respective element from `compareTableau` array by `index`.

```
var labels = [
  ["string1", "string2", "string3"],
  ["string1b", "string2b", "string3b"]
];
var tableauCompare = ["string4", "string4b"];

var result = labels.map((el, i) => el.concat(tableauCompare[i]));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var labels = [
  ["string1", "string2", "string3"],
  ["string1b", "string2b", "string3b"]
];
var tableauCompare = ["string4", "string4b"];

var result = labels.map((el, i) => el.concat(tableauCompare[i]));

console.log(result);
```